# Proxy Click not functioning in Modal

Tags: r, shiny

Using the Shiny package in R, I'm trying to create a modal that will close upon hitting "Enter" while focus is inside the text box. Hitting "Enter" is the same as pressing the provided button using some javascript I found: Credit: Dean Attali. Source: https://github.com/daattali/advanced-shiny/blob/master/proxy-click/app.R

I have slightly modified my source code to print whatever you type in the text box after hitting "Enter" or clicking the button.  It is currently functioning when not in a modal:

```
library(shiny)

jscode <- '
$(function() {
var $els = $("[data-proxy-click]");
$.each(
$els,
function(idx, el) {
var $el = $(el);
var $proxy = $("#" + $el.data("proxyClick"));
$el.keydown(function (e) {
if (e.keyCode == 13) {
$proxy.click();
}
});
}
);
});
'

ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton("button", "Button"),
  tags$head(tags$script(HTML(jscode))),
  tagAppendAttributes(
    textInput("text", "Text", NULL),
    `data-proxy-click` = "button"
  ),
  textOutput("input_text")
)


server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$input_text <- renderText({
    input$button
    paste0("You typed: ", isolate(input$text))
  })
}


shinyApp(ui, server)
```

But when I try to do the same from inside a Modal, hitting "Enter" while focused inside the text box doesn't work. However, clicking the Button *does* do what I want it to: Close the modal and print out the text typed into the text box.

```
library(shiny)

jscode <- '
$(function() {
var $els = $("[data-proxy-click]");
$.each(
$els,
function(idx, el) {
var $el = $(el);
var $proxy = $("#" + $el.data("proxyClick"));
$el.keydown(function (e) {
if (e.keyCode == 13) {
$proxy.click();
}
});
}
);
});
'

ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton('modal', 'Modal Window'),
  textOutput("input_text")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  observeEvent(input$modal, {
    showModal(modalDialog(
      actionButton("button", "Button"),
      tags$head(tags$script(HTML(jscode))),
      tagAppendAttributes(
        textInput("text", "Text", NULL),
        `data-proxy-click` = "button"
      )
    ))
  })

  observeEvent(input$button, {
    removeModal()
  })

  output$input_text <- renderText({
    input$button
    paste0("You typed:", isolate(input$text))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Is there a way to have hitting "Enter" while focused in the Modal text box to properly function the same as pressing the 'button'?  I'm still a novice to any type of coding, so any help or suggestions are appreciated! 
 Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I replaced your jscode with something I found online a while back and it seems to work:

```
jscode <- '
$(document).keyup(function(event) {
    if ((event.keyCode == 13)) {
        $("#button").click();
    }
});
'
```

You can then remove the tagAppendAttributes so your observeEvent looks like this:

```
  observeEvent(input$modal, {
    showModal(modalDialog(
      actionButton("button", "Button"),
      textInput("text", "Text", NULL)
    ))
  })
```

This makes the code a lot simpler although I'm sure your way could work too - just unsure how.

**Update**

Full code below just in case as I removed this line incorrectly above:

```
tags$head(tags$script(HTML(jscode))),
```

meaning that the jscode never got loaded and the enter key would still not work as desired.

*Full edited code:*

```
library(shiny)

jscode <- '
$(document).keyup(function(event) {
    if ((event.keyCode == 13)) {
        $("#button").click();
    }
});
'

ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton('modal', 'Modal Window'),
  textOutput("input_text")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  observeEvent(input$modal, {
    showModal(modalDialog(
      actionButton("button", "Button"),
      tags$head(tags$script(HTML(jscode))),
      textInput("text", "Text", NULL)
    ))
  })

  observeEvent(input$button, {
    removeModal()
  })

  output$input_text <- renderText({
    input$button
    paste0("You typed:", isolate(input$text))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, Eli.   I replaced the code and it seems to be functioning the same as it was before:  Clicking the button is working, while hitting enter with the text box focused does not.  Replacing the code as you suggested was working on your end?

Comment: Yes, on my side the replacement jscode makes hitting enter the same as clicking on the button.

Comment: I'm sorry, it seems I removed the actual loading of the jscode when I put it in the answer which could explain things. Please try my updated answer above.

Comment: What actually happened was I put the loading in the ui as you have it in your first simple example but forgot to put that in the answer. That will teach me to always clear the environment, restart R and test fresh before answering and maybe to always add full answers to be sure.

Comment: Excellent! Looks like it is working as desired. Thanks again!

Comment: Sure, happy to help!

Comment: Just for clarification - the text box doesn't need to be focused for the pressing Enter to function within the Modal.  This does work great for my purpose, but just wanted to point that out.

Comment: That is a good point. Yes, this code is independent of the text box unlike your original code. It would be nice if someone could give us a solution using the proxy click.